# Request.post wait for it to end NodeJS

Tags: node.js, post, request

I have to make multiple REST API Post calls in sequence. (Output of 1st REST api, the processing done by first api will be input of next).

How do I make a request.post() call in NodeJS to finish before returning? I think request.post() is asynchronous and I need to make it synchronous. I tried using callbacks but it didn't work.

```
function abc(ip, op) {
    let options = {
        url: 'http://localhost:123/s',
        form: {
            ipath: ip,
            opath: op
        }
    };
    request.post(options);
}
```

REST API call

```
app.post('/s', (req,res)=>{
    gm(img_path).implode(-1.2).write(op_path, function(err) {
        if (err)
            console.log(err);
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it synchronously, but what you can do is wrap it in a `Promise` or use [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise), and use **[async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)**/**[await](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/await)**, to wait for the result of `abc` before calling the other function.

```
const request = require('request-promise');

function abc(ip, op) {
    let options = {
        url: 'http://localhost:123/s',
        form: {
            ipath: ip,
            opath: op
        }
    };

    // This returns a promise when using request-promise
    return request.post(options);
}


async function myFunction() {

    const ip = ''; // Whatever ip / op are
    const op = '';

    const abcRes = await abc(ip, op);

    // This won't run until `abc` finishes
    const otherCallRes = await otherCall(abcRes);

    // Do something else with otherCallRes

    return otherCallRes;

}

myFunction()
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Do i need to make abc() as async function as well? I'm getting error 'SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function' but I have made myFunction as async.

Comment: No, you don't need since you're not using `await` in `abc` we're just returning a promise. Which node version are you using? `async/await` is available since 7.6. The code I give you doesn't have any errors, besides from `otherCall` not being defined. So show the code where you're getting the error.

Comment: @ashish1512 so, did you find the error in your code?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! It works! I was using a for-each loop which is why it was throwing the error. I converted it to a for-of loop.